# How does python lists manage values of different data types?

Tags: python

If I am not wrong, python lists are linked lists, lets say we have a list

```
L =['a',34]
```

According to my understanding it looks like this

```
 _  __       ___ __
|_a|_*| --> |_34|__|
```

And from C we know that pointer next to 'a' will point to a data type similar to its own, i.e. in this case a 'char', but how does python here manage to do this

I tried to see the source code it hurt my head, can someone please explain its working in simple words

Edit: I've been banned from posting after posting this question and I don't understand why

Comment: Python is more of a high-level programming language than C. It most likely treats every datatype as an object with its own metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think every variable in python is actually stored as a structure, containing datatype and then the raw data. So behind the scenes every variable is actually of the same type (which is this structure).

https://realpython.com/python-variables/

Comment: makes sense. Could you please refer me to some documentation regarding this

Comment: It isn't documentation, but it's something.